# Google Cloud DataPrep DATEDIF function inconsistent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, etl, google-cloud-dataprep

I have four DateTime columns, all in long format eg `2016-08-01T21:13:02Z`. They are called `EnqDateTime`, `QuoteCreatedDateTime`, `BookingCreatedDateTime` and `RejAt`.

I want to add columns for the duration (in days) between `EnquiryDateTime` and the other three columns, i.e.

```
DATEDIF(EnqDateTime, QuoteCreatedDateTime, day)
```

This works for `RejAt`, but throws an error for all the other columns:

```
Parameter "rhs" accepts only ["Datetime"]
```

As per the image below, all four columns *are* DateTime.

[image: Column setup showing working RejAt DATEDIFF]

Can anyone see any other reason this may not be working for 2 of the three columns?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the image below, I reproduced an scenario such as the one you presented here, and I had no issue with it. I create the three columns `X2Y` using the same formula that you shared:

```
DATEDIF(EnqDateTime, QuoteCreatedDateTime, day)
DATEDIF(EnqDateTime, BookingCreatedDateTime, day)
DATEDIF(EnqDateTime, RejAt, day)
```

[image]

My guessing is that, for some reason, the columns do not have an appropriate `Datetime` format. Maybe you can try applying some transformations to the data in order to make sure that the data contained in the columns has the appropriate format. I recommend that you try doing the following:

- Clean all missing values, clicking on the column and then `Clean > Missing > Fill with NULL`. Missing values can prevent Dataprep from recognizing a data type properly.
- Change the data type again to Datetime, just to doublecheck that there is not any field that does not have the `Datetime` type. You can do so by clicking on the column and then `Change type > Date/Time`.

If these methods do not solve your issue, maybe you can try working with a minimal example, having only a few rows, so that you can narrow down the variables with which to work. Then you can update your question with more information.

It would also be nice to know where are you getting the error `Parameter "rhs" accepts only ["Datetime"]`. It is not clear for me what the `rhs` (Right Hand Side) parameter is in this case, so maybe you can also provide more details about that.